# How will we install Ros Indigo on ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to install Ros Indigo On Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS because it is stable version of Ubuntu.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218002/how-will-we-install-ros-indigo-on-ubuntu-14.04.3-lts?/) by [NEO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23984/neo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you experiencing problems using the [normal installation instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu)? If so, please *edit* your question with more information.

The linked instructions should work on 14.04.03.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23984/neo/) on 2015-09-25**:
oh I am sorry, I have installed ROS on Ubuntu 14.04.3. Its fine.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2015-09-26**:
@NEO, please either accept or close the question as not relevant or outdated.